# Problem loading image in user-uploaded images in Profile page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am a beginner to Django (version = 5.0) and I have issue in viewing user-uploaded content on their profile page that is being rendered on HTML. I have installed Pillow library properly and I tried all methods but I can't seem to understand what the issue seems to be.

views.py

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    return render(request, "register_user/profile.html")
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from register_user import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# url patterns 

app_name = 'register_user'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="register-index"),
    path("signup/", views.userRegister, name="register-user"),
    path("login/", auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='register_user/login.html'), name="login"),
    # path("login/", views.login_user ,name="login"),
    path("profile/", views.user_profile, name="profile"),
    path("logout/", views.logout_user, name="logout"),
] 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default = "default.jpg", upload_to='profile_pics')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.user.username} Profile"
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'static'
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]

# MEDIA 
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"
MEDIA_URL = "media/"
```

profile.html

```
{% block content_block %}
   
  <div class="card border-light mb-3" >

    <img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-header">Username ~ {{ user.username }}</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</h5>
      <p class="card-title"> Your email -> {{user.email}} </p>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock content_block %}
```

I created a profile object through admin and uploaded an image. And then I tried displaying it through profile.html and it shows this error->
[this is visible in console when i go to profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m43Ia.png)
edit: I have changed the upload_to = 'profile_pics' and uploaded the wrong screenshot by mistake, however the issue still remains

I have tried resizing the image to make it smaller and have also manually checked that the image is present in that folder by going to that directory. I am clueless, kindly help.

The uploaded image is not visible on profile page so I want to know if it is a problem with my laptop or I have used wrong syntax somewhere.
I expect to see the uploaded image on the profile page

Answer (score 1):

Should work. I tried the same code and it works for me. Is the user authenticated?

Comment: Hey! yes the user is authenticated and I have successfully resolved the error with the help of the very helpful people at the official django forum. It seemed like I was adding the Media_Root and url at the wrong urls.py file. Instead of adding it to root urls.py file, I had added it to the app urls.py file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved with the very kind help from people at the official Django forum! It seems like I was adding the
`static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`
part to the wrong urls.py file.

I had added this to urls.py of my app(register_user) instead of declaring it in the root urls.py which was causing the image to not load!

For reference, this is my urls.py of register_user app now->

```
from django.urls import path
from register_user import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


# url patterns 

app_name = 'register_user'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="register-index"),
    path("signup/", views.userRegister, name="register-user"),
    path("login/", auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='register_user/login.html'), name="login"),
    # path("login/", views.login_user ,name="login"),
    path("profile/", views.user_profile, name="profile"),
    path("logout/", views.logout_user, name="logout"),
]
```

And this is my root urls.py ->

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include('blog.urls')),
    path("register/", include('register_user.urls')),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```